# Reading emails from my own server

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer for PHP on my site.

How can I read my own emails, by PHPMailer?

I have looked at: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/PHPMailer, but I didn't see any good example for PHPMailer using POP3.

I would be glade having a little code that explain the use of PHPMailer with pop3.

Thanks :)

Comment: I have changed a bit of my original question (So my question will be cleared). I looked at google, but didn't see any good example specifically for PHPMailer working with POP3 to receiving my emails. Need help about. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your working with Yii Framework, then you easily can doing with [EIMAP Yii Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eimap/), for more help try this link - https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: As my question, I would like sample for PHPMailer working with POP3 in order receiving emails. Thanks :)

Comment: regarding to your sound it's not possible through POP3, try this link - [link](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php), you will get the idea.

Comment: I have tried this link - what shall I do? For first test, I want to loop all of my emails, and read them. I need a code sample please. I didn't find any in google. Thanks :)

Comment: just download the zip file from this url - [http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eimap/](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eimap/), check these source code. whole code written in php, so you will get the idea.